# How to change commenting style generated by shortkey in xcode?

Tags: xcode, comments

I just started using XCode 4.3, but don't like how the IDE comments multiple lines.

When I select more than 1 line then hit the short key (command + / ), it puts "//" in front of each lines.

Is it possible to make it to use /* */ and // for multiple lines and single line respectively?

Comment: do you get any luck on this. I mean how to put /* */ by shortcut key

Answer (score 1):

No, using /* */ for multiple code line with help of shortcut is not possible. You will have to do it manually.
And for commenting single line, move editing vertical bar to specific line and press ctrl+/ .